# create friends list between users in django web application

Tags: python, django

I am building a web application in Django and I'm creating users through the Users auth.

I would like to add the feature for users to be able to add other users(e.g using username) and build friends list.

I came across some libraries (friendship, relationship etc) but most of them are outdated and not serving my purpose.

So yeah I would like to see if you guys have any implementation ideas.

Cheers,
Nicolas

Comment: and where are your ideas?

Comment: I initially started implementing, similarly with the answer below,but then I wanted to see if any such libraries already exist. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to achieve this is to implement a model which extends the functionality of built-in django user model. The sketch is below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User) # you can also define this relationship to MyUser
```